# Using fgets() to read from different pipes, reading same message from both (should be different)

Tags: c, pipe, fgets

Im using fgets to read from 2 different pipes which have been sent 2 different messages thus should be returning 2 different messages. I have 2 pipes for each and closed the unneeded child end, all my fprintfs are flushed yet theyre both returning the same message then it just hangs. I have no idea why. Debugging didnt help me though i could have missed something.

```
int reader(FILE *output, int **pipes, char *getMessage) {
if(output == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Player quit\n");
}
fgets(getMessage, sizeof(getMessage), output);
printf("mes %s\n", getMessage);
return 0;
```

}

Is my reader method (I am using the same buffer for both but i was using memset to try to clear it each time:

```
printf("test%c\n", roundDeck[deckPos]);
            fprintf(input[pickturn], "yourturn %c\n", roundDeck[deckPos]);
            fprintf(stdout, "yourturn %c\n", roundDeck[deckPos]);
            fflush(input[pickturn]);
            allHeldCards[pickturn][1] = roundDeck[deckPos];
            roundDeck[deckPos] = '-';
            //fclose(inPut);
            deckPos++;
            if(deckPos == 16) {
                deckPos = 0;
            }
            printf("pt %d\n", pickturn);
            reader(output[pickturn], pipes, getMessage);
            if(msgProcess(pickturn, allIds, allFlags, allHeldCards,
                    getMessage, pipes, roundDeck,
                    deckPos, numPlayers, input) == 1) {
                roundDeck[deckPos] = '-';
                deckPos++;
                if(deckPos == 16) {
                deckPos = 0;
                }
            }
            memset(getMessage, 0, 50);
```

the inputs were changing where they needed to do on the outside so maybe Im using memset incorrectly?

Comment: You will have to post some code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Possibly you are using the same buffer for both messages.

Comment: Can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: Why doesn't `reader()` use any of your `pipes`? `sizeof(getMessage)` is obviously wrong. Why are you reading from a file pointer called `output`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem here:

```
fgets(getMessage, sizeof(getMessage), output);
```

Since `getMessage` has type `char *`, then `sizeof(getMessage)` is `sizeof(char *)` which is likely to be `4` or `8`.  You read that many bytes from the "output" into `getMessage`.

Instead, you need to specify how many bytes to read.  Even if you replace `sizeof(getMessage)` with your buffer size, that means it will block until all that number of bytes have been read, or the input is closed.  Either your message protocol has to contain the length it expects to read, or you have to define your function to read until the input is closed or a certain delimiter occurs.

Then you have to make sure that the data you read contains a null-terminated string before you try and print it with `%s` or any other function that expects a string.

Not clear why your inputs are called `output` and your outputs are called `input` either.

It's hard to debug further without seeing more of a complete program than just these snippets

Comment: Are you confusing `fgets()` with `read()`, here? In the absence of empty input or error, `fgets()` will always null terminate the string, and obviously it will stop reading on a newline character so there's already a delimiter.